# React Native: display message when user click on send button without refresh

Tags: react-native

I had create a simple chat app systeme using only states.

```
class Messages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        msg: [], //all messages in db
        msgS: '', // message send on click
      }
  }
  async sendMsgS() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('key', '***'); // API key
      formData.append('userId', '1');
      formData.append('msg', this.state.msgS);
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://www.globalfidelio.com/gfn_arcol/api/send_msg.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
      });

      let res = await response.json();

      if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300 ) {

        console.warn("message envoyé " + res.message);

      } else {
        let errors = res;
        throw errors;
      }

    } catch (errors) {
        console.warn("error msg is_  " + errors);
    }
  };
  onPressSend() {
    this.sendMsgS().then(() => {
      this.setState({msgS: ''})
    });
    console.log(this.state.msg.Conversation.reverse());
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getMsgFromApi().then(data => {
      this.setState({ msg: data})
    });

  };
```

it works fine but when I click on sen button I have to refresh to display the message I sent, what I want it's display my sent message without refreshing.
I have no idea how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding extraData flatlist prop:

```
  <FlatList
    style={Styles.flatlist}
    data={this.state.msg.Conversation}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.datetime.toString()}
    extraData={this.state} //this prop
    renderItem={({item}) => <MsgR msg={item}/>}
    inverted= {-1}
  />
```

and when I click the send button, I re-call getMsgFromApi() method:

```
onPressSend() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(USERID_STORED)
      .then(userIdStore => {
              this.setState({ userId: userIdStore});
              this.sendMsgS(this.state.userId).then(() => {
                this.setState({msgS: ''});
this method --> this.getMsgFromApi(this.state.userId).then(data => {
                  this.setState({ msg: data,});
                });
              });
      });
}
```

and it's work fine: when I click on send button, I have the message sent displayed after a few ms, it's unpleasant but it works !

Answer (score 0):

It's react behaviour. If you change state, react calls render method. To avoid this you can use this lifecycle method:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

I couldn't see your render method to see how you are displaying msg. However you can't display any changes without refresh(but alerts).

Here shouldComponentUpdate docs [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: I display my message with componentDidMount(). can you give me an exemple ? I have to replace componentDidMount with shouldComponentUpdate or what ?

Comment: how do you display message? With alert?

Comment: no with flatlist
              <FlatList
                style={Styles.flatlist}
                data={this.state.msg.Conversation}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.datetime.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => <MsgR msg={item}/>}
                inverted= {-1}
              />

Comment: As I said above: You can't display anything without refresh. After any state change, react calls render method and **refresh only necessary parts**. What is your problem with refreshing?

Comment: I have to display massages that I send and that I reveive from API but without refreshing. like a real time chat app

Comment: After setState refresh will be automatically so that user doesn't have to do anything. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Here an example: https://snack.expo.io/@mirzakilic/sample?session_id=snack-session-wKsI3wyu2